# Dynamically update doInBackground params in AsyncTask

Tags: android, performance, android-activity, android-asynctask

Just wondering if there is a possible way to update the data of AsyncTask's doInBackground. Like for example rotating an image, I use bitmap which I want to update each time the UI thread gets a new data, I want to pass that data to AsyncTask which it can work in the background.

Any tips for that? Thanks

Comment: Just start new AsyncTask instance and pass new data to execute method or AsyncTask constructor

Answer (score 2):

`AsyncTask` is meant to do a small amount of work and exit. They are not meant for long running operations, so it wouldn't be appropriate to try to pass new data into it.

It sounds like what you should do is:

1. UI gets a new image
2. Start a new async task to process the image. Store task in member variable.
3. If UI gets a new image again, check if existing async task is still running. Either cancel that task and start a new one, or discard the new image and let the current task run to completion.